# Unable to read content of SAP BI report in xml format?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

> http://localhost:6405/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/6127/reports/2/

adding **logontoken** and **accept: application/xml** as headers, Iam not getting the content of the report but getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<report>
<id>2</id>
<name>test</name>
<reference>2.RS</reference>
<showDataChanges>false</showDataChanges>
<style>
<hyperLinkColors visited="#000000" link="#0000ff" hover="#000000" active="#000000" />
</style>
<pageSettings>
<margins left="2835" right="2835" top="2835" bottom="2835" />
<format orientation="Portrait" height="42094" width="29764" />
<records vertical="100" horizontal="20" />
<scaling factor="100" />
 </pageSettings>
 </report
```

What should i do to get content in xml format?

Answer (score 1):

Use **text/xml** instead of **application/xml**.

Comment: it shows the content including the style tags which i dont want, I want to get only the data of the report @Joe

Comment: Then you probably don't want xml format, but one of the others such as csv.

Answer (score 0):

This call is the report output with complete layout which allows you to render by yourself a report in your application (for example, if you want to build an Office add-in).

If you want only the data of the report, here is how you can do. First, retrieves [the list of elements in your report](https://uacp2.hana.ondemand.com/viewer/58f583a7643e48cf944cf554eb961f5b/4.2/en-US/7da1aeaa6f701014aaab767bb0e91070.html).

```
http://localhost:6405/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/6127/reports/2/elements
```

Then parse the response (which can be either xml or json) and for each elements of type table, you [can retrieve its dataset](https://uacp2.hana.ondemand.com/viewer/58f583a7643e48cf944cf554eb961f5b/4.2/en-US/e84c9bb575304628a010a735d4326bd9.html) with the following call:

```
http://localhost:6405/biprws/raylight/v1/documents/6127/reports/2/elements/<elementID>/dataset
```